# Can't set font for Navigation Bar in Storyboard of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I cannot set font for `Navigation Bar` in my `NavigationController` using story board. I checked some questions here. They told options to change the font available in `Attributes Inspector`. But when I checked there I can't select custom fonts for my `NavigationBar`. You can see that in below screen shot.

[image]

You can see the Font Family field is disabled. So please help me to change the `Navigation Bar` font from story board. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just change Custom to System and change again to Custom. Im not sure why, but this worked for me!

Comment: worked for me too @Juan. Thanks. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Your welcome! Accept my answer and mark it as correct, a lot of people has this problem and doesnt know how to fix it

Comment: that this is still an issue in XCode 11.5 in 2020 is mind boggling...this solution still works

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom font with code if you want that font in all project just add it to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                      [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontname" size:24.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
```